# What's the best way to implement message queue on medium traffic website

Tags: php, symfony, message-queue, rabbitmq

First off, some basic information about my project: I have a website with about 1000 visitors a day, built with Symfony 2. For some tasks I'm thinking about implementing a message queue, Rabbit MQ would be my first choice based on some internet reviews.

But I think I'm going to have a lot of different task types (in the first stage about 10 tasks), and they aren't going to be run that very much. For instance: I want a message queue for sending e-mails: I want these to be sent immediately, so creating a cron job is not really acceptable, but my website will maybe send 5 e-mails a day.

Now I'm wondering if it's better to create message queues for every task type. In which case I will have to run 10 concurrent consumers. Or create one 'generic' queue, which just executes a Symfony2 Command with the parameters in the message.

I think the best and most "pure" solution would be the first (10 queues), but I'm worried it's a bit 'overdone'...

So does anyone have any experience with this is willing to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating different queues for each unique task that you need to be executed, and assign priorities to the queues so that the most important actions are executed first even if they are added later on with other messages in the queue.

In your queue processor you can execute different commands using the message body as parameters.

Comment: Yes, I really think this is the "best" way to implement it, but I'm a bit concerned that I'll have to instantiate 10 consumer (for every queue one), and track that they're all running. This makes deployment a bit harder (should be no real reason though), and because most queues will probably get less than 10 messages a day I wondered if it was the best way to do it...

Maybe I was secretly hoping someone had an ever better solution, that I hadn't tought of ;-)

Comment: You can process one queue message at a time and once completed, then you move to the next message. You also setup a lock to ensure that only one queue processing action is proceeding at any one time and a job to restart processing if it terminates. I have used such a model to process about 500,000 messages which were for an initial application load

Comment: If I understand you correctly: Just create one task (Symfony CLI process), which cycles the queues and processes them accordingly?
Then why is the lock needed? Doesn't RabbitMQ provide this? But I like the idea :-) Thank you :D

Comment: I am not very familiar with RabbitMQ, but you can create one CLI task which reads messages from the queue and processes them, then delete the message from RabbitMQ when processing is completed successfully. You can even execute different commands depending on which queue the message is from. The lock is needed for the CLI script processing of the messages, to ensure only one instance is running at a time. When processing fails, the lock file remains so you can delete it after a specified period of time (make it large enough to ensure the processing has completed safely)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to test/implement this somewhere this week ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same situation. I am interrested in building something similar.

Unfortunately I am still trying to setup the project. I spent the day so far and now I can send and recieve messages. I need to continue figuring out how and what is relevant in the "service" definition the documentation refers to.

When I have an answer, i'll definely add my answer.

So far, what I did:

1. Download Symfony 2
2. Added the following submodules

   ```
   git submodule add git://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle.git vendor/bundles/OldSound/RabbitMqBundle
   git submodule add git://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib.git endor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib
   ```
3. Followed instructions on [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle).

... I have something working, but not yet figured out how what works by which conventions.

Comment: I had RabbitMqBundle already in mind for solving this problem, but my problem is more wether I should create one 'generic' queue (where each task executes a Symfony task), or create a separate queue for each task...

Comment: Same issue here BTW.  I am thinking of creating a Bundle that will listen to events recieved by creating consumers classes. I am actively reading about it. We could setup a Wiki page somewhere to share our notes if you want ;)

Comment: @renoirb ever get that Wiki up? Looking to implement something like this

Comment: Hi.  No i did not do it yet.  I am about to implement it now though. When I started this thread, I was begining my project and did not needed it, now I will. I'll keep you posted.